# Printing/placing a float with desired amount of decimal places

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, char

I want to print/place (`sprintf`) a float variable with as many decimal places as I like into a char array. E.g:

So here I would want it to 1 decimal place, SPECIFIER being the specifier for 1 decimal place:

```
float FLOAT = 1.10000124f;
char FLOAT2[32];
sprintf(FLOAT2, "%SPECIFER" FLOAT);
printf("%s", FLOAT2);
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. See if `"%.1f"` is the format specifier you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Specifer: %.1f
1 being the decimal places